# Converting Date-Time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) format to seconds in EXCEL

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a long list of "date-time" data which are formatted as (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) and sorted in chronological order.
What I want to achieve is setting the first "date-time" as "0s" and set the succeeding "date-time" with reference to "0s".
For example, if the first date is 2015-01-01 00:00:00 and nth date is 2015-01-02 00:00:00, then since exactly 24 hours=86400 seconds passed, I want the "date-time" to be converted to "0" for the first datum and "86400" for the nth datum. I don't want them to be renewed when the day passes.
I tried to achieve this by simply subtracting the 1st datum form the nth datum, but I confronted the problem of seconds getting renewed when the day pass. I need some concrete hint about solving this problem or if there is simple function for achieving this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simply do:

```
=A2-A1
```

And custom format the cell:

```
[s]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The way of formatting the cell was a great help!

Comment: @LucasSeo, as long as you realize that multiplying the subtraction will alter the actual timevalue. If there is no need for further calculations, I guess it's fine. Otherwise, formatting would be a saver option to maintain your original value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply put this formula into the desired cell:

```
=(A2-A1)*86400
```